# Session variables MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, session

Is there an easy way to see what session variables exist and their values using Visual Studio running an MVC3 application in debug mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output something like this:-

```
foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
{
    Response.Write(key + " - " + Session[key] + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: This seems the best way as there seems no way to check what session variables exist through Visual Studio at run/debug time.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's a "normal" ASP.NET application:
Try `Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session`

Normally you can use "Session" directly, e.g.

```
Session["key"]
```

You may try it in an immediate window in debug mode ...

Comment: I don't think I explained myself very well - apologies.  If I don't know all the variables that are in a session, is there a way to list/see them all and their associated values in debug mode?